# Spark ML: how to copy all params from a model to another

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

In Spark I have set all the params of an Estimator using the setters. Now I want to copy all those values to another Estimator which is an existing val inside another class. I could use the setters one by one on the second instance, but I would like to copy all the params at once, just like `copyValues()` does - but `copyValues` is private :-(

I have tried calling `mymodel.extractParamMap()`and then traverse it calling `othermodel.set(param, value)` without modifying anything, but the original Params already have a parent object set, so I later get an error when Spark realizes the new model is not the owner (parent) of those params.

I cannot (at least not easily) create new Param instances (with the new parent updated) because each original Param belongs to some subclass of Params (say, DoubleParam, etc) which I cannot retrieve while traversing the param map, unless I use reflection for this.

I cannot just create a new `ParamPair` with the same origina value without first specifying something about the underlying type of the param. I could do some sort of pattern matching for each possible type (say `IntParam`, `DoubleParam`, ...) to create the appropriate (parent-updated) Param type in each case (I tried and it works), but that's ugly and not elegant at all.

Isn't there a simpler way to transfer all the parameter values at once from one model (Estimator) to another existing one? Something like `copyValues` but for the general public :-)

Comment: There should be a get/set parammap look at the Scala docs for the api

Comment: That's what I thought but no luck: 
[Esimator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator)

and ALS which is my case: [ALS](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS)

You can see only one public [set method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS@set[T](param:org.apache.spark.ml.param.Param[T],value:T):Params.this.type) which receives a Param (which should be parameterized for the desired type, or a proper Param subclass) and a value

Comment: I think it is called extractParamMap

Answer (score 0):

I can show you in Python if it helps, I guess it's similar in Scala. For example if we have:

```
rf = RandomForestRegressor(featuresCol = 'features', labelCol = 'TARGET', predictionCol='prediccion',
                       numTrees = 46)
```

You can obtain the dict param like:

```
params = {param[0].name: param[1] for param in rf.extractParamMap().items()}
```

and create a new model :

```
new_rf = RandomForestRegressor(**params)
```